# jQuery calendar in .net app

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, calendar

I have a table that has all the meeting schedules. I need to display the schedules in a Calendar on an Aspx page.

The calendar should:

- allow the users to export the meetings to outlook
- display time in different time zone specified in a dropdown list box.
- have security based on different users' level of access (a field in the user table)
- display in day, week, month, year.
- display meetings in different colors for different meeting committees.

I use C#, .net 2.0, jQuery. Is there any existing code/add on that has already done this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) will provide *some* of that functionality.  I had to implement a similar calendar, and I used FullCalendar to provide the base functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Day Pilot (Light) is free and open source.  It doesn't do everything you need but at least you can expand on it.  http://www.daypilot.org/demo/Lite/

Answer (score 0):

[DevExpress' Scheduler](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Scheduler/) control would do most of this for you.  It's not free though.  Demos can be found [here](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxSchedulerDemos/Default.aspx).

Comment: not really a fan of devexpress. It causes more headaches than good and it loads really slow.

Comment: @SeeSharp I hear you there.  My company has been using it and in many cases we're frustrated to no end with it, but in the unique cases of this calendar control and their gridview it has actually helped (although getting the calendar to work the way we wanted it to was a pain too :P)